# I would like to write a sql (Oracle SQL) query to select a part of a string from a column after a specific character

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to write a sql (Oracle SQL) query to select a part of a string from a column after a specific character

Example

Please see the table below:

```
Column A                                 

J:\JAVA\CIA TEST DBMS\AdobeDocument.pdf  
J:\JAVA\CIA TEST DBMS\wordDocument.docx
```

Now for each value in column A, i want to extract the string like

`.pdf` from first value  (`J:\JAVA\CIA TEST DBMS\AdobeDocument.pdf`)

`.docx` from second value (`J:\JAVA\CIA TEST DBMS\wordDocument.docx`)

Here the specific character for the string is . from the end of the string

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What should the query return if there are no dots in the string? Or is it guaranteed beforehand that all paths end with a file name (not a folder), and all file names have an extension?

Comment: Thank you for asking a good question. The answer is not all the values in the column will have extensions like .pdf, .doc etc...In such case we have to ignore such values.

Comment: So - return NULL for those rows? Or not include the rows in the output of the query in the first place?

Comment: not include the rows in the output of the query .

Answer (score 1):

Using the `SUBSTR + INSTR` method

The 3rd argument `-1` of `INSTR` searches backwards for a dot, `SUBSTR` here gives you the characters starting from that index till the end.

```
WITH t(A)
AS
(
select 'J:\JAVA\CIA TEST DBMS\AdobeDocument.pdf' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 'J:\JAVA\CIA TEST DBMS\wordDocument.docx' FROM DUAL
)
select SUBSTR( A,INSTR(A ,'.',-1 )) FROM t;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f58ce79da17823f1087bc1fb031d5b22)

Comment: Hi Kaushik... the solution you gave worked for me but if i want to list the distinct values how can i do it??                 Example: In the DB if there are two files with .pdf extension, then i would like to list the .pdf only once in the output.

Comment: @VenkataRamanaMurthy : I don't understand what do you mean by *"if there are two files with .pdf extension"*. Edit your question and show us more examples to cover all scenarios and the expected result for each case.

Comment: From the OP's answers - the query should not return anything if there is no dot in the string (your solution will return the entire string; easy to fix with a WHERE condition, to exclude rows that don't include a dot); and he wants to `select DISTINCT substr.......`

Answer (score 0):

Besides Kaushik's suggestion you might [***try***](http://rextester.com/HOF95871) `regexp_substr()` function with `'[^.]*$'` pattern :

```
with tab(str) as
(
 select 'J:\JAVA\CIA TEST DBMS\AdobeDocument2.pdf' from dual union all
 select 'J:\JAVA\CIA TEST DBMS\AdobeDocument.pdf'  from dual union all
 select 'J:\JAVA\CIA TEST DBMS\wordDocument.docx'  from dual
)
select distinct regexp_substr(str,'\.[^.]*$') as str 
  from tab;

STR
------
.pdf
.docx
```

p.s. just use `distinct` in front of *regexp_substr expression* to get distinct results of *file types*.

Comment: It seems the OP wants to include the dot in the output. When you add that to the regexp, remember to escape the dot.

Comment: @mathguy OK, just now I've realised and edited, thanks.

Comment: @mathguy I couldn't understand what you mean by `escape the dot`

Comment: Oh! In a regular expression `.` is a wildcard character - it stands for ANY character. (Except in a bracketed expression where it stands for itself.) To represent an actual dot, you must escape it with a backslash: `\.`. By accident, in this case it wouldn't matter - if the character matched in your expression was not the dot itself, then it would be part of `[^.]*` so the match would be extended one more character to the left... until the wildcard `.` matches an actual dot. But that is just by accident.

Comment: @mathguy Thank you so much, actually I also guessed "\" as the escape character before but as you've mentioned no problem arised by sake of this particular case, and didn't consider using that. Thank you again.